# How persist a custom api on a Motorola FX7400 RFID reader after a reset?

Tags: .net, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

I need to develop an application in .Net for a Motorola rfid reader (FX7400). This device runs    Windows Ce 5.0. I know how to run applications on the device. I just synchronized with it using Active Sync. But what I can't do is prevent that when the device is reseted all my stuff (including custom apps installed by me) gets cleaned up from the device.

**Is it necessary for this purpose to build a new OS for the device? Is there another simpler way to perform this?**

Thanks.

Comment: If I am not completely mistaken, your question is not related to RFID at all - you may want to remove the rfid label from your question.

Comment: I think you are right. I will remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is placing your application in a persistent memory location, like the /Application partition on the Motorola FX7400.
Then you need to create a shortcut to your application and place it on the same partition.
The last step is to create a .cpy file and place it in the /Platform partition (I can't remember the exact path, but it shouldn't be hard to find). This .cpy file is executed every time the reader restarts so you need to have in the .cpy file the instruction to copy your shortcut to the Startup folder, I believe it is Windows/Startup.
For what you need to write in the .cpy file you can read one of the few .cpy files in the /Platform partition.

Hope this helps.

Also, a few tips for easy access of the FX7400:
1. If you just need easy copy and paste you can access the reader using ftp. Just type the reader's address with ftp as the protocol used and insert credentials
2. If you need to see the user interface of the device (it has one it's just not that easily accessible) you can install Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys and once you are connected with Active Sync to the device you need to start ActiveSync_Remote_Display (name pretty much says what it does).

Comment: That works!!!! Thank you so much for your help. You are a genius. Just one more question. How can I create a shortcut for my application on the FX7400? I need to use the visual interface or there is another way to do that? Anyway than you for your help.

Comment: It has been a few months since I have worked with the FX7400 but I think there are two ways to create a shortcut: 1. Remote_Display selecting your application and using the File... menu and Send To-> Desktop as Shortcut. The second method: You need to find a shortcut on the device I believe there is one in the root folder. You the copy that onto your PC and open it witth a text editor like Notepad++. You will see that it is mainly text. You need to replace that text with 33#"\Application\MyApp.exe" After this you save the file (preserving the .lnk extension) and copy it to the device.

Comment: Very cool! I'm happy I revived the thread so you finally got your answer :-) However I am going to remove my answer in turn since it did not really help - the devices seem to be too different.